# YTMUSIC ERROR: 'YTMusic' object has no attribute 'parser'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

I've a problem with ytmusicapi. I used it for some tests and was all ok, but now when I search for a song I get this error: 'YTMusic' object has no attribute 'parser'.
Here is a test:

```
from ytmusicapi import YTMusic

ytmusic = YTMusic()

ric = ytmusic.search("fix you coldplay")
print(ric)
```

I tried to analyze the script and I created an isoleted one but nothing.
Can you help me?

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the complete error

Comment: Yes. 
    ric = ytmusic.search("fix you coldplay")
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ytmusicapi/mixins/search.py", line 178, in search
    search_results.extend(self.parser.parse_search_results(results, type, category))
AttributeError: 'YTMusic' object has no attribute 'parser'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using an older version of `ytmusicapi`. Just update it with `pip install -U ytmusicapi` and it will work. I tested it on my machine and it works

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.